# AVX code segfaults when compiled with -ffast-math?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, simd, fast-math

I'm experimenting with writing a couple kernels using GCCs builtin simd support.  I've got this code benchmarking an AVX dot product kernel:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// define rtdsc instruction
static __inline__ uint64_t tick(void) {
    uint32_t hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (uint64_t)lo)|( ((uint64_t)hi)<<32 );
}

// AVX dot product 
float avx_dot(float* __restrict__ ans, float* __restrict__ A, float* __restrict__ B, int N, ssize_t nprod, ssize_t shift) {
    assert(N % 32 == 0 && "N not divisible by 32");
    const int VECTOR_SIZE = 8;

    typedef float vec
        __attribute__ ((vector_size (sizeof(float) * VECTOR_SIZE)));

    N /= VECTOR_SIZE;

    for (ssize_t ii=0; ii < nprod; ii++) {
        vec *Av = (vec*)A;
        vec *Bv = (vec*)(B + ii*shift);

        vec temp[4] = {0,0,0,0};
        for(int jj = 0; jj < N; jj += 4) {
            temp[0] += Av[jj+0] * Bv[jj+0];
            temp[1] += Av[jj+1] * Bv[jj+1];
            temp[2] += Av[jj+2] * Bv[jj+2];
            temp[3] += Av[jj+3] * Bv[jj+3];
        }

        union {
            vec   tempv;
            float tempf[VECTOR_SIZE];
        };

        tempv = temp[0] + temp[1] + temp[2] + temp[3];

        ans[ii] = 0;
        for(int jj = 0; jj < VECTOR_SIZE; ++jj) {
            ans[ii] += tempf[jj];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    const ssize_t NITER   = 1000;
    const ssize_t DECIM   = atoi(argv[2]);
    const ssize_t DOTPROD = atoi(argv[3]);
    ssize_t size = atoi(argv[1]);

    float* A; posix_memalign((void**)&A, 128, size*sizeof(float));
    float* B; posix_memalign((void**)&B, 128, (size+(DOTPROD-1)*DECIM)*sizeof(float));

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (ssize_t ii=0; ii < size;                   ii++) A[ii] = rand();
    for (ssize_t ii=0; ii < size+(DOTPROD-1)*DECIM; ii++) B[ii] = rand();

    printf("# size: %i  nproducts: %i  shift: %i\n", size, DOTPROD, DECIM);
    printf("# iter  answer  cycles  seconds  samprate\n");
    float results[DOTPROD];
    for (ssize_t ii=0; ii < NITER; ii++) {
        uint64_t beg = tick();
        avx_dot(results, A, B, size, DOTPROD, DECIM);
        uint64_t end = tick();

        float ans = 0;
        for (ssize_t jj=0; jj < DOTPROD; jj++) {
            ans += results[jj];
        }

        double    CLOCK   = 3300e6; 
        uint64_t cycles   = end-beg;
        double   seconds  = (double)cycles/CLOCK;
        double   samprate = (size*DOTPROD)/seconds;

        printf("%-5zd %f %lli %.3e %e\n", ii, ans, (unsigned long long)cycles, seconds, samprate);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Strangely, when compiled with:

```
g++ -O3 -march=corei7-avx dotprod.cc -ffast-math -o dotprod
```

I get a segfault the first time I access temp inside avx_dot.  But, when compiled with:

```
g++ -O3 -march=corei7-avx dotprod.cc -o dotprod
```

IE, without -ffast-math on, it runs fine.  I'm very puzzled as fast-math shouldn't affect memory access I believe, so I don't know where the segfault is coming from.

I'm running on:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
```

Can anyone confirm this behavior on their machine and shed some light on what's happening?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the asm?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not necessarily the best at raw assembly, but I'll take a look

Comment: run it under gcc, and show us the insn it faults on.  Also, there's `-march=sandybridge`.  IDK how it's different from `-march=corei7-avx`.  BTW, you shouldn't be getting faults from auto-vectorization, unless you somehow told gcc that your data was aligned, but then it turned out not to be.  (`vmovaps` will fault on unaligned addresses, unlike AVX memory operands to other instructions.  `vmovups` has the same performance.)  Oh, you did, with that typedef I guess.  The `_mm256_loadu_ps` vs. `_mm256_load_ps` intrinsics exist to communicate alignment information to the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My random guess is data-alignment, considering that it fails loading data (failing instruction is .... vmovaps (%rcx),%ymm4 ... %rcx=0x603228 and Bv is located 0x603228, and reading documentation on that instruction reveals requirement of 16 bytes alignment).

Further investigation:

Problems happens when Bv is offset 8 bytes into B, due to this line (and AVX requires 16byte alignment):

```
vec *Bv = (vec*)(B + ii*shift);


./dotprod-fast 64 10 10
A=0x1125080
B=0x1125200
# size: 64  nproducts: 10  shift: 10
# iter  answer  cycles  seconds  samprate
Av=0x1125080
Bv=0x1125200
Av=0x1125080
Bv=0x1125228
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: It requires 32-byte alignment for the `ymm` form, but yes, you're probably right.

Comment: Only the aligned load/store instructions have alignment requirements in AVX.  One of the major AVX features is that memory operands don't require alignment, so `vaddps  ymm0, ymm1, [mem]` is safe even if the data might sometimes be unaligned.  There's a perf penalty for crossing cache-line boundaries, but if the data is *usually* aligned at run-time then it makes sense to keep the aligned case as fast as possible and let the hardware handle the unaligned cases with only a small slowdown.